# Spring-boot-jdbcTemplate Unit-testing

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5, jdbctemplate

I am new to Spring and only somewhat experienced with JUnit I have the following method which requires a unit test

```
@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> executeSqlQuery(String sql) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> downloadRequest = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
        return downloadRequest;

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve this using JUni?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these ways to unit test the function

1. **Mocking the JDBC class** :

   The JDBCTemplate is a dependency for our class. Since in the unit test we moock the dependency, we could unit test this function by mocking the `jdbcTemplate` class.
2. **Using an in-memory database** :

   If we are mocking the JDBC itself, you will see that we are not achieving much from the unit test.

   One other practice which is followed is to use an in-memory database, you can use H2 Database. In this case, we will create the actual records in an in-memory database and then the query will be run over this fake database. This way we can insert multiple records in the database and check that our query is working fine. If you are using Spring, you can simply add @JdbcTest annotation on the test class to use H2 Database.

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-testing